# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Node<ValueType> *' to 'Node<ValueType> *'

Tags: c++

I am working on a homework assignment where we aren't allowed to use any STL containers. My implementation of LinkedList is a collection of Nodes that are chained together with pointers. I have another class called ContinuousList which has a data member LinkedList whose Nodes contain pointers to Nodes in various other LinkedLists. I'm trying to assign the return value of a function that returns a pointer to a Node to a variable that is also a pointer to a Node, but it is saying that is invalid and I don't understand why I can't do that.

```
template <typename ValueType>
struct Node
{
    Node();
    std::string m_key;
    ValueType m_value;
    Node<ValueType>* m_next;
};
```

The linked list class:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    Node<ValueType>* begin()
    {
        return m_head;
    }
private:
    Node<ValueType>* m_head;
};
```

ContinuousList:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class ContinuousList
{
public:
    ValueType* iterate(std::string& key)
    {
        m_curr = m_collection.begin(); // Error occurs here

        ...
    }
private:
    LinkedList<Node<ValueType>*> m_collection;
    Node<ValueType>* m_curr;
};
```

Full error message

```
1>          error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Node<ValueType> *' to 'Node<ValueType> *'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              ValueType=Node<bool> *
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              ValueType=bool
1>          ]
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>          while compiling class template member function 'bool *ContinuousList<ValueType>::iterate(std::string &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              ValueType=bool
1>          ]
1>          see reference to class template instantiation 'ContinuousList<ValueType>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              ValueType=bool
1>          ]
```

Comment: You are missing semicolons at the end of the class declarations, maybe just copy-paste error?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Can you post a complete test-case?

Comment: Yes, that was just an error when I was trying to remove the irrelevant code bits. I am using Visual Studio 2010 under Windows. I added the full error message text to the OP if that helps at all. The compiler fails immediately when I try to construct ContinuousList<bool> test_results;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    LinkedList<Node<ValueType>*> m_collection;
```

this

is making m_head be

```
      Node<Node<ValueType>*>*
```

Which is not what you want.

```
    m_curr = m_collection.begin()
    Node<ValueType> = Node<Node<ValueType>*>*
```

if

```
    Node<Node<ValueType>*>*
```

was what you wanted, use

m_collection.begin()->m_value;

or use

```
    LinkedList<ValueType>,
```

and it will return Node

Though I may just be really tired.... =D

Comment: In other news, Node< gets treated as html tags it seems

Comment: Both of the answers were great but you have less rep so I accepted yours :)

Answer (score 4):

The error message I get from GCC is:

```
cannot convert ‘Node<Node<int>*>*’ to ‘Node<int>*’ in assignment
```

which is slightly clearer than the nonsense your compiler gives.

`m_collection` contains nodes wrapped in nodes. Depending on what you're planning to do with it, perhaps it should just be `LinkedList<ValueType>`, or perhaps the assignment should be `m_curr = m_collection.begin()->m_value`.

Also, `ContinuousList::iterate` should almost certainly take its argument by `const` reference.

Comment: That you that was exactly the problem. I completely forgot that there was another step after following the first pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In `LinkedList` definition you assume `ValueType` to be a `Node` parameter, but in `ContinuousList` you give `Node<ValueType>` as a `LinkedList` template parameter:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class ContinuousList
{
// (...)
    LinkedList<Node<ValueType>*> m_collection;
    Node<ValueType>* m_curr;
};
```

so your `LinkedList` actually looks like:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    Node<Node<ValueType> >* begin()
    {
        return m_head;
    }
private:
    Node<Node<ValueType> >* m_head;
};
```

and this is obvioulsy not valid when you want to do this:

```
/*Node<ValueType>* */ m_curr = /* Node<Node<ValueType> >* */ m_collection.begin();
```